How many engineers/scientists believed that human flight was imminent as of the late 19th/early 20th century?
An article was famously written in 1903 arguing that human flight is potentially millions of years away, while in reality the first flight took place just 69 days later:

Hence, if it requires, say, a thousand years to fit for easy flight a bird which started with rudimentary wings, or ten thousand for one which started with no wings at all and had to sprout them ab initio, it might be assumed that the flying machine which will really fly might be evolved by the combined and continuous efforts of mathematicians and mechanicians in from one million to ten million years — provided, of course, we can meanwhile eliminate such little drawbacks and embarrassments as the existing relation between weight and strength in inorganic materials. No doubt the problem has attractions for those it interests, but to the ordinary man it would seem as if effort might be employed more profitably.


What was the prevailing opinion among scientists and engineers about the feasibility of powered human flight in the years immediately preceding 1903?

How common was the Wright brothers' optimism about imminent success in aviation among their scientific peers or the engineering community at large? The 1903 editorial makes it sound like the general public was highly skeptical but doesn't tell us anything about the opinion of more educated people.


For a recent example of public and scientific opinion having a huge delta, see the COVID vaccine. There was broad consensus around them being feasible to develop very quickly among scientists but the general public was extremely skeptical.

What has your own research shown? At a minimum, every other inventor working on their own airplane would have believed in their own imminent success.

This does, of course, depend heavily (pun intended) on what you consider "human flight". Humans had already achieved flight in balloons and gliders long before the Wright Brothers. They were just the first to achieve heavier-than-air, powered, controlled flight (although the 'controlled' part wasn't all that good). They did that by building on the work of others. You might want to look at NASA's page on the History of Flight

@SPavel I've found that the Wright brothers had some competition but no data on what the attitude of (say) members of the Royal Society were on this matter.

There was broad consensus around them being feasible to develop very quickly among scientists but the general public was extremely skeptical. I don't think this is true. Many experts were also skeptical even about Fauci's hope that a vaccine would be developed in 12 to 18 months. The "general public" probably didn't have much of an opinion either way. (Trump, whom we might consider a member of the "general public", claimed it would take only 3 to 4 months under his brilliant leadership.)

@user103496 Moderna had a working vaccine back in January 2020, so Trump was indeed correct. The biggest problem was scaling the manufacturing, not developing the vaccine itself. AFAIK actual experts in immunology and vaccine development (<10k such people worldwide, simply having an MD doesn't count) were pretty aligned on this being possible. Proving that the vaccine works could've also been done in ~2 weeks via a challenge trial but no such trials were sadly approved.

Note that it was, and still is, a long tradition to naysay things.  Someone famously demonstrated that trains going too quickly would collapse human lungs.  I recall reading in Science & Vie, a French equivalent of Popular Mechanics, a detailed expose of why stealth airplanes were physically impossible, right before the F117 came out of skunkworks.

Decades ago Arthur C. Clarke wrote Profiles of the Future, which speculated about what various fields could come to if the development were pushed as far as possible.  He started with two chapters "The Hazards of Prophecy: Failures of Nerve" and "The Failures of Prophecy: Failures of Imagination".  The first is devoted to people who put out wildly bad predictions and who had the information to know better.  It makes a good read.

One who comes in for particular scorn had an important British position and tried to predict the ultimate performance of the airplane, which was vastly short of what was demonstrated in a decade or two.

A similar question: who would have considered the almost entire collapse of the horse (animal) powered industries.

Moderna had a working vaccine back in January 2020 So all the experts who in April 2020 thought it would take at least another 18 months to get a vaccine were completely confused and wrong? What the Wikipedia page you linked to says is this, Moderna announced development of an RNA vaccine. Not that it had a "working vaccine". A developed vaccine is one that's ready to be rolled out, not one in the early stages of development.

Richard Pearse, 9 or 21 months earlier - "Hold my beer." || Pearse specifically said he did NOT establish controlled flight before the Wright Brothers, but it seems he managed maybe about 50m of " less than fully controlled flight" 21 months before their first flight. 31 March 1902 or 1903.|| Importantly, the remains of his first attempt lay where he "landed" for many years. They were then dug out and are now on display in a  cabinet in Auckland NZ MOTAT (Museum of Transport and Technology). || ...

..  Among the more holy aviation's relics that I have seen - along with the Red Baron's compass and joystick, in the Canberra War Memorial Museum, Australia.

@user103496 mRNA-1273 from January 2020 was almost identical to the final approved version. The biggest challenge was scaling the manufacturing to deliver billions of doses. all the experts who in April 2020 thought it would take at least another 18 months to get a vaccine => were they experts in vaccine development and immunology specifically? A lot of the "experts" were just random MDs, actual experts in vaccine development were much more optimistic. But like I said, there are <10k such people in the entire world, so 99% of the talking heads on TV were not qualified to give an opinion.

You ask exclusively about the attitude/opinions of experts/professionals; but this might point you to some evidence that not all public opinion was skeptical: I remember in early 2000 that NPR (the US "National Public Radio") aired a segment about a time-capsule that had been buried or hidden in 1900, with instructions that it was to be opened 100 years later. One of the items was a list of written questions for the future reader. I remember being fascinated, but i can only actually remember one of the questions: "Have you learned to fly?"

Opinions were divided. First, you should make your question more precise: the human flight was possible since 18th century, using balloons. So the question was about "heavier-than-air" apparatus which can lift a human. Also gliders existed and flied with humans since 1894, at least. So in 1903 the question was only
about "powered flight in an apparatus heavier than air".
Some physicists and mathematicians indeed did not believe that this is possible. And the reason was that there was no good theory of the lifting force.
The first such theory could be derived from the Newton's theory of air resistance, and it predicted that for small angles of attack, the lifting force is proportional to the square of the angle of attack. If this was correct, an airplane flying at moderate speeds would be hardly possible.
To the embarrassment of mathematicians, the correct formula for the lifting force (suitable for moderate speeds) was produced only shortly AFTER the first airplane flight.
Remark. Much later it turned out that Newton's theory is a better approximation to reality for the hypersonic speeds:-)
For technical detail of this story, you may consult this text:
https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/airplanes.pdf

Wonderful link! Looks like Kutta first published his initial formula in 1902 but the full theory wasn't ready till 1906.

Joukowski published the same formula in 1904. But I don't know when this formula became known to practical aviators.

George Cayley first questioned Newtons square sine law in 1809. The first wind tunnel of 1871 likewise proved that the formula cannot be correct. The Wright brothers ended up relying on Lillianthals tables which were derived by observing bird flight, plus their own wind tunnel.

@JonathanReez Lilienthals investigations were inspired by observing bird flight, but the tables are the result of systematic experimentation, for example with a rotating apparatus, to which he attached wings of different geometries and measured the resulting forces. His book describes the experiments in detail.

@ccprog thanks! Found the version with "Tafel/Table VI" present, which shows the key chart used for figuring out the angle of attack. If I understand correctly they've used an angle of 3 degrees but as per our best formulas today, the optimal is around 5 degrees.

@JonathanReez ah that is better, makes it possible to link to the rotating appartus used to measure the forces in two dimensions.

Here is a short and incomplete list of scientists and engineers that were actively working on realising human flight at the end of the 19th century, with more or less success:

England: George Cayley, Percey Pilcher
France: Louis Mouillard
Germany: Otto Lilienthal
Austria: Wilhelm Kress
Russia: Nicolai Zhukowski, Alexander Mozhaysky
USA: Samuel Langley, Octave Chanute, the Wrights

They were mostly in correspondence with each other, most of them published books and articles about their achievements, which were translated into several languages. They were no tinkerers, working in the privacy of their homes, but learned scientists, engineers and entrepreneurs, who were part of their communities.
Those that wanted to know about the developments in the field of aerodynamics and human flight could know it was something a lot of people were working on, and were making progress in.

Chanute was French by birth, but wasn't all of his aviation work done in the US? He'd lived there since childhood. Not terribly important, I suppose.

@hobbs you are right of course, corrected.

Note also Richard Pearse - see my comment on the question. He WAS a tinkerer working in his own home BUT his many inventions were well known to his community.

Powered and controllable aircraft were built and flown from the 1880s on, e.g. this French example. Some prototypes were built even earlier. I am sure interested engineers and scientists would have been aware of these.
If the "really fly" from the article is about flying like a bird (with flapping wings) then we still seem to be quite far from making it practical?

Manned flights with ornithopters (flying machines with "flapping wings") have been around since at least 1942.

Yes but how was the airship in that link significantly different from the Montgolfier balloon?
Personally I see heated air and lighter-than-air gas as far more similar than different.
I'm not quite suggesting that airships and balloons deserve less status in 'human flight' than aeroplanes but what holds me back is little less than the difference between the the common term 'manned flight' and the OQ's 'human flight.'
I don't think this is the place but people might like to discuss whether that difference is so small it matters not or so great, it over-rides everything else.

"Powered and controllable". A balloon will just fly where the wind blows.
